# Need free time slots from dynamic time in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime, time

There is one pitch and pitch has its own start time and end time (e.g from 8:00 AM to 7:00 PM).
And multiple matches has already been scheduled on pitch with some time. (e.g from 8:30AM to 9:00AM, 10:00 AM to 10:30 AM)
So now what i want to calculate is available time on pitch. 
My code is here:

```
$pitchStart = '2018-06-11 08:00 AM';
$pitchClose = '2018-06-11 09:00 PM';

$firstGameStart = '2018-06-11 09:30 AM';
$firstGameEnd = '2018-06-11 10:00 AM';

$secondGameStart = '2018-06-11 10:00 AM';
$secondGameEnd = '2018-06-11 10:30 AM';

$thirdGameStart = '2018-06-11 11:00 AM';
$thirdGameEnd = '2018-06-11 11:30 AM';


$Result = [
    [0] => ['freeSlotStart' => '2018-06-11 08:00 AM','freeSlotEnd' => '2018-06-11 09:30 AM'],
    [1] => ['freeSlotStart' => '2018-06-11 10:30 AM','freeSlotEnd' => '2018-06-11 11:00 AM'],
    [2] => ['freeSlotStart' => '2018-06-11 11:30 AM','freeSlotEnd' => '2018-06-11 09:00 PM'],
];
```

Comment: Is a `match` always 30 minutes?

Comment: No it can vary. @IvankaTodorova

Comment: And I assume that matches can start on `11:35 AM` or `09:12`?

Comment: Also how do you know the match's duration?

Comment: Yes  @IvankaTodorova Actually tournament creator can set the match duration while creating tournament.

Answer (score 2):

The code below shows how to get all used slots (based on an interval).

```
<?php

$pitchStart = new DateTime('2018-06-11 08:00 AM');
$pitchClose = new DateTime('2018-06-11 09:00 PM');

$games = [
    [
        'start' => new DateTime('2018-06-11 09:00 AM'),
        'end' => new DateTime('2018-06-11 10:00 AM')
    ],
    [
        'start' => new DateTime('2018-06-11 10:30 AM'),
        'end' => new DateTime('2018-06-11 10:43 AM')
    ],
    [
        'start' => new DateTime('2018-06-11 11:00 AM'),
        'end' => new DateTime('2018-06-11 11:55 AM')
    ]
];

//This is the time slots interval
$slot_interval = new DateInterval("PT30M"); //30 Minutes

//Get all slots between $pitchStart and $pitchClose
$all_slots = [];

$slots_start = $pitchStart;
$slots_end = $pitchClose;

//This is how you can generate the intervals based on $pitchStart / $pitchClose and $slot_interval
while($slots_start->getTimestamp() < $slots_end->getTimestamp()) {
    $all_slots[] = [
        'start' => clone $slots_start, 
        'end' => (clone $slots_start)->add($slot_interval)
    ];
    $slots_start->add($slot_interval);
}

function slots_used_by_game($slots, $games, $slot_interval) {
    $slots_taken = [];

    foreach($games as $game){
        $game_duration = $game['end']->diff($game['start']);
        $game_duration_in_minutes = (float)($game_duration->h * 60 + $game_duration->i);

        $number_of_slots = ceil($game_duration_in_minutes / $slot_interval);

        foreach($slots as $key => $slot) {
            if($game['start'] <= $slot['start']) {
                $slots_taken = array_merge($slots_taken, array_slice($slots, $key, $number_of_slots));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $slots_taken;
}

$used_slots = slots_used_by_game($all_slots, $games, 30);

//Print them all for testing
foreach($all_slots as $slot) {
    echo $slot['start']->format('Y-m-d H:i'). ' - '.$slot['end']->format('Y-m-d H:i').PHP_EOL;
    echo ((in_array($slot, $used_slots)) ? 'NOT AVAILABLE' : 'AVAILABLE').PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you response @ivanka. But match duration can be vary so this piece of code wouldn't work.

Comment: Well, you said the tournament creator sets match duration, right? So if I create a tournament & say I want match duration to be 30 minutes, it means that people still can play more than 30 minutes?

Comment: @AshishParmar I have updated my code to work with all kinds of match duration.

Comment: If i changed the first array of game the result will showing wrong : `[
        'start' => new DateTime('2018-06-11 09:28 AM'),
        'end' => new DateTime('2018-06-11 09:58 AM')
    ],`